# Use iPad as Monitor

Tags: hdmi, ipad

If I purchase this [iPad HDMI Adapter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005HRT88G), could I plug in a DVD player to my iPad? Or would this device only work as an output?

Comment: The iPad video output can be connected to a TV.

Comment: @Ramhound - thank you that is what I was after, was turning it into an input device.

Comment: There is software out there that lets you use an iPad as a second monitor, presumably over wifi. To be clear on what Ramhound said (it strikes me you might have misunderstood him/her), the thing you linked to will allow you to output the image on the iPad (sans protected video content in some apps) to an external TV/monitor.

Comment: @Darren - so if I Purchased one of these apps, I would be able to play a DVD from an external DVD player on my IPAD display?

Comment: Oh, I glossed over the DVD player part. The software I'm talking about is to use the iPad as an external computer monitor. I'm not sure if playing a DVD on your PC would work in this case. Best bet would be to rip the DVD to a file, use something like Handbrake to covert it to an iPad friendly format and either copy it to the iPad or stream it with DLNA.

Comment: @Darren - That is what I was thinking.  Was trying to avoid ripping it, DLNA is a good option tho.

Comment: @StarsFlyFreeFromCozyNights - You do realize my comment basically said, you cannot hook your iPad to a DVD Player right?  My comment is a implicent confirmation iPad can be connected to a TV and an explicent confirmation the iPad cannot be connected to a DVD Player.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the iPad HDMI adapter does not have video input capability. You can use the iPad as a second screen for your computer using the Duet app, but it's not a general-purpose display.